# The setTimeout method works strangely

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, settimeout

I have created a method to let the user wait for certain period of time. (waiting window)

```
function hideMe()                                                                
{                                                                                
  document.getElementById('rotate').style.visibility= "hidden";                       
}                                                                                

function showMe()                                                                
{                                                                                
 document.getElementById('rotate').style.visibility= "visible";                    
}                                                                                
function wait()                                                                
{                                                                              
  showMe();                                                                   
  setTimeout(hideMe, 2000);   // To show certain window for 2 seconds         
}
```

But the window just flashes even I increase the time longer. It doesn't improve a lot.

1. Why is that?
2. What is the alternative method?
   Well, I can't use jQuery in this project, sorry.

**UPDATE**
Sorry... I use `visibility` instead of `display` but it still can't work.
I found out that I will send some requests to server after the command `wait()` and it influences `setTimeout()`.

like:

```
wait();
httpReq();
```

If I add `alert("after wait()")`
like:

```
wait();
alert("after");
```

The alert won't be executed after the `wait()`;

Comment: works here http://jsfiddle.net/cj6ozjj3/

Comment: Valid values for `style.display` are `"block"`, `"inline"` and `"none"`.  `"visible"` is not a valid value.

Comment: Sorry for this mistake. But please see `UPDATE`

Answer (score 2):

in your code you are using

```
document.getElementById('rotate').style.display= "visible";
```

where display does not have "visible" property.
You either have to use "block","inline".
or you can also set display property to blank.

```
document.getElementById('rotate').style.display= "";
```

Check if this helps.
As per OP's comment

setTimeout is not synchronous command. if you want something to be execute out after the setTimeout is executed. You have to add it to setTimeout function. For Eg

```
setTimeout(function(){hideMe();alert("test");}, 2000);
```

Comment: setTimeout is not synchronous command. if you want something to be execute out after the setTimeout is executed. You have to add it to setTimeout function.
For Eg setTimeout(function(){hideMe();alert("test");}, 2000);

Comment: Well, that's terrible. If I have lots of function, I need to write `setTimeout(func1, func2..., time);` Btw: Please update the answer

Comment: If you can tell me, what exactly is your requirement then might be i am able to help you.

Comment: Well, I just feel that `setTimeout(func1, func2..., time);` is ugly. Can I use a synchronous command similar to `setTimeout()`

Comment: I didn't understand your Q properly, and  setTimeout is "asynchronous" function.But i think what you want to achieve is what jquery does in http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/. This will slowly fadeout your element and you can also pass callback function which will  get execute only after animation is complete